# How do you create an effect like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knows how to make the faded effect thing like that. As far as I'm aware that could be possibly done with pixel sorting but I was wondering if anyone would know an easier way to do it. Preferably in Photoshop.

Comment: "Faded", as in "the colors are faded"? What is your starting image? Is increasing brightness and decreasing contrast enough?

Comment: Filter > Stylize > Wind > Blast

Comment: http://puu.sh/rEsWo/0452cc2da9.jpg   I tried something like that but I don't know, it feels a bit off than what I'm trying to do. Also in the image that I posted initially perhaps the creator had a better original that came out like that. And as in faded I meant like how the colors smudge to a side.

Answer (score 1):

## Pixel Sorting

It's the name of this effect ([Google search](https://www.google.es/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1863&bih=1136&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=3A3ZXMOvE5ur1fAPxrCjSA&q=Pixel%20sorting&oq=Pixel%20sorting&gs_l=img.3..35i39j0i30l9.12567.13679..14017...0.0..0.70.450.7......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0.gy-xq3U9pe4#imgrc=_)).

> Pixel sorting is an interesting, glitchy effect which selectively orders the pixels in the rows/columns of an image.

[image]

Image and more info [here](http://satyarth.me/articles/pixel-sorting/)

---

In Photoshop, Menu Filter → Stilize → Wind once and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win to increase the effect.

[image: Wind]

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

There's a free action download at [spoongraphics](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/free-pixel-sorting-photoshop-action-for-creating-glitch-art)

Answer (score -1):

This looks like what happens when your Windows XP crashes and you have that draggable popup that won't stop printing on the screen.

I'd say you can do this with the clone stamp tool where you grab the same few pixels and drag across, or duplicate the layer and drag to the right side. I don't see any particularly easy way of doing this besides what Scott says, messing with the Wind filter. 
Additionally you can also use the Fibre filter, and use the layer overlay mode over a coloured background. The little end points will have to be drawn by you, though.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? Otherwise better add this as a comment.