# how is this glitch effect achieved?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, glitch

[image]

is this done with design software or is it a genuine glitch/ai generated image? any help would be immensely appreciated <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create an effect like this in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78374/how-do-you-create-an-effect-like-this-in-photoshop)

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate because we already had this question answered before. Check out the duplicate, hopefully it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop...

`Filter > Stylize > Wind`

[image]